# How to integrate keycloak in Spring Boot with a different context root and reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak

We are currently developing a microservice application using Spring Boot 1.4 and Keycloak 2.5.0 (configured as openid-connect service) using the Keycloak Spring Adapter (not the Spring Boot adapter).

All of our microservices are put behind a load balancer and an additional reverse proxy as the application will be hosted on an existing domain behind a context root (so the root of our application is http://foo.bar/foobar/ and the rest services are http://foo.bar/foobar/rest/).

We are facing a couple of problems with Keycloak in this given scenario:

1. Keycloak forward to /sso/login if a sign-in is needed. This is in our case unwanted behaviour because http://foo.bar/sso/login will not exist. I have found a way to change the forward but there is no way to make Keycloak listen to the same url; we end up with a 404 in this case.
2. After signing in, Keycloak redirects back to the /sso/login url with the correct tokens, but if this is not the same server, the request fails and it redirects us to http://foo.bar/. Since every microservice exposes /sso/login, this can be in fact a completely different server.
3. If keycloak is hosted on the same domain, we end up in a redirect loop. We would also like to have Keycloak hosted on the same domain and on the context root http://foo.bar/foobar/auth/ .

We've already tried using the `"token-store": "cookie"` but this did not resolve the problem.

Is there a way to resolve these problems or is Keycloak maybe not the correct solution for our use-case ?

---

**Update 05/05/2017**: 
Move my answer from here to an answer

Comment: Another problem is that once authenticated, we get redirected directly to our server, so instead of going to http://foo.bar/foobar/rest/service we're being redirected to http://localhost:8080/rest/service

Comment: Hey, I faced the same problem and I did resolve it using a similar config. Could you add your solution as a response and check this question as a resolved? It will be easier to see what to do for the next one reading this.

Comment: Okay, moved it to an answer. If your solution was somehow different, can you also specify it ?

Comment: Actually not, it was the same solution. What I meant is that the config was a little bit different. I faced almost the same problem, but I wanted a bearer-only app and I got redirects that I don't wanted. Much appreciate for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are now up and running with Keycloak so I'll briefly explain what we did. The front-end of our application runs Angular2 and we created a custom login page in the Angular application itself (so it's not a theme for Keycloak) which will directly query the Keycloak API for an OAuth2 Bearer token. The front-end will send this token on each request in the Authorization header (as per the OAuth standards). 
On the service side we have configured keycloak as a bearer-only solution (`bearer-only: true` in the keycloak.json), this way the application just returns a 401 or a 403 instead of forwarding to the login page.

Using this configuration the user will never see anything from the /sso/login page and there is also no redirect issue anymore.

*TLDR; the use-case I described was also not realistic, calling a REST URL and then forwarding to a login page is kind of bad stuff :)*